Method interceptor in micronaut not executing
I implemented a micronaut method interceptor to clear functional interface beans after execution.
This is the annotation I implemented:
/**
 * Annotate on method. If method was called, the bean bound to this message will be destroyed.
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Around
public @interface Job {
}

And this is the method interceptor:
@Singleton
@InterceptorBean(Job.class)
public class JobExecutionTracker implements MethodInterceptor<Object, Object> {
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    /**
     * Destroys bean of declaring type of the method context.
     *
     * @param context The context
     * @return method result.
     */
    @Override
    public @Nullable Object intercept(MethodInvocationContext<Object, Object> context) {
        Object result = context.proceed();
        Class<Object> jobType = context.getDeclaringType();
        logger.debug("Destroyed Job: {}", applicationContext.destroyBean(jobType));
        return result;
    }
}

When I inject a bean with a method that is annotated with Job inside a MicronautTest or inside the application, the method inceptor is not triggered. I got no debug message. What am i doing wrong?
